# sar shows zero percent load

Tags: linux, sar, sysstat

I have an issue with `sar` on several machines running ORACLE Linux 6.4. Sometimes it shows zero load (CPU, block device, whatever else), including idle:

[image]
Why can it happen?

sysstat package version is 9.0.4-20.el6.x86_64.

Comment: Load average is not a percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU shows zero for all fields probably because it has been set offline.

From sar's manual page:

"On SMP machines a processor that does not have any activity at all
(0.00 for every field) is a disabled (offline) processor."